# In Jetpack Compose, enabling enableEdgeToEdge with WindowInsets(0.dp) glitches statusbar padding at start

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, edge-to-edge

While rendering the first frame of an edge-to-edge application with Jetpack Compose, the height of the statusbar is ignored, resulting in jerking of UI. How to solve this?

First vs next frames:

[image]

This image shows glitching of the main content, but beyond this, the TopAppBar itself is often rendered without indentation. This is very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, just add `WindowInsets.safeDrawing` anywhere before the UI description. The first call to this function always returns 0, the next ones work correctly.

For example, at the very beginning of setContent:

[image]

Or, to hide this line, inside AppTheme:

[image]